# C - Malloc-ing a Pointer Passed to a Function

Tags: c

I'm working on a simple problem on a coding-challenge website, but have run into a practical complication based on how the coding environment is set up. I am solving this in C. The function declaration/arguments are supplied for you. The supplied arguments are a pointer to an array of `int`'s, an `int` for the number of array elements, and another pointer to an `int` which I *assume* is an array that I'm to put my solution in:

```
int* smallerNumbersThanCurrent(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize)
{
    /* My solution... */
}
```

In a loop where I allocate my solution to each `i`th element, I get an out-of-bounds runtime error. There is also this comment above:

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
```

Obviously indicating that whatever memory it points to hasn't been allocated which needs to be the same size as the input array. I tried to do this:

```
/* Error-checking */
returnSize = (int*)malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int));
/* Rest of the solution... */
```

But this leads to a buffer overflow. The website kicks back a bunch of memory addresses around this showing where the error is, but this isn't very helpful.

Obviously a sloppy solution is just to reallocate another array of the size I need and return the pointer to that, but the site is clearly checking for the solution in the array that *it* points to, and as I don't allocate to it the system reports my array as empty.

I'm not sure how to work with `int *returnSize`, or what the automated test suite is actually using it for. Could anybody tell me where I'm going wrong, and why what I have tried so far has failed? Thankyou.

**Edit:** The problem spec from the website. It is fairly uninformative and simply describes the problem itself rather than pragmatically how the skeleton is set up.

```
Given the array nums, for each nums[i] find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than it. That is, for each nums[i] you have to count the number of valid j's such that j != i and nums[j] < nums[i].

Return the answer in an array.



Example 1:

Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
Output: [4,0,1,1,3]
Explanation: 
For nums[0]=8 there exist four smaller numbers than it (1, 2, 2 and 3). 
For nums[1]=1 does not exist any smaller number than it.
For nums[2]=2 there exist one smaller number than it (1). 
For nums[3]=2 there exist one smaller number than it (1). 
For nums[4]=3 there exist three smaller numbers than it (1, 2 and 2).

Example 2:

Input: nums = [6,5,4,8]
Output: [2,1,0,3]

Example 3:

Input: nums = [7,7,7,7]
Output: [0,0,0,0]



Constraints:

    2 <= nums.length <= 500
    0 <= nums[i] <= 100
```

The website is *Leetcode*, problem #1365 (https://leetcode.com/problems/how-many-numbers-are-smaller-than-the-current-number/).
The function declaration I included above is all that is present when the problem is started. I should note I have also had multiple solutions working on my own machine compiling with `GCC`, including:

Declaring a pointer in `main()`, and `malloc`ing the memory for it in the function.
`malloc`ing the array in `main()` and passing it as an argument.
Foregoing the 3rd argument, `malloc`ing the array inside the function and returning a pointer to it.

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Link the site or quote the exact description of the problem because from this amount of info it just guessing. I mean your function returns with a pointer to int so my guess you should return the pointer to the created array and put it size to `returnSize`, but this is just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

> The supplied arguments are a pointer to an array of int's, an int for
>   the number of array elements, and another pointer to an int which I
>   *assume* is an array that I'm to put my solution in:

Your assumption does not seem consistent with the naming of the `returnSize` argument.  Moreover, your function **cannot** return a pointer to the allocated space via `returnSize` as it is *passed by value*.  If it initially points to an existing object then you can manipulate the pointed-to object through it, but changes the function makes to the pointer itself are not visible to the caller.

Inasmuch as the function's return type is `int *`, it seems reasonable to suppose that the function is expected to *return* a pointer to whatever space is allocated.  The `returnSize` argument is then presumably expected to be used to convey the size of the allocated space (or at least the number of elements used) back to the caller, since that caller cannot determine that from just a pointer to the data.

That is, it appears `*returnSize` complements the function's return value in the same way that its `numSize` argument complements its `nums` argument.